# How to find the PID of a running command in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi3, pid, gnu-screen

I've googled this question, but never found anything useful for my particular case.

So, what I'm trying to figure out is the PID of a certain command that is running so I can kill it if necessary. I know it's possible to get the PID of a command by typing `echo $!` So supposedly

```
my_command & echo $!
```

should give me the PID. But this isn't the case, and I think I know why:
My command is as follows:

```
screen -d -m -S Radio /path/to/folder -f frequency -r path/to/song
```

which opens a detached `screen` first and then types the command so that it gets executed and keeps on running in the background. This way the PID that `echo` shows me is the wrong one. I'm guessing it shows me PID of `screen -d -m -S Radio /path/to/folder -f frequency -r path/to/song` instead of the PID of the command run in the new terminal created by screen.

But there's another problem to it: when I run `screen -ls` in the terminal, the command that is running in the background doesn't show up! I'm fairly certain it's running because the Pi is constantly at 25% CPU usage (instead of the 0% or 1% usually) and when I type `ps au` I can actually see the command and the PID.

So now I'm calling the community: any idea on how I could find the PID of that certain command in the new terminal? I'm writing a bash script, so it has to be possible to obtain the PID through code. Perfect would be a command that stores the PID in a variable!

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: `pgrep -f search_pattern` -- add the `-l` flag if the output is for human consumption.

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman , your comment worked for me. Somehow I now have the PID of the command!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @glennjackman I managed to get the PID I wanted with a simple `pgrep search_word`. At first it wasn't working, but somehow I made it work after some trial and error. For those wanting the PID on a variable, just type

`pid=$(pgrep search_word)`

Regarding the problem with `screen -ls` not showing my detached session, it's still not solved, but I'm not bothered with it. Thanks again for solving my problem @glennjackman !

EDIT:

Second problem solved, check the comments on berends answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily find out all the running process and their PID by writing (for example):

```
ps aux
```

The process is run by screen so you can probably find it easier by writing:

```
ps aux | grep screen
```

For more info about ps and the parameters I used check (quick google) -> https://www.lifewire.com/g00/uses-of-linux-ps-command-4058715?i10c

EDIT: You can use this command with bash scripting as well.

Comment: Thank you. The grep somehow helped me, but as I said: I need it to be in a script. I know how to find it on my own on the the terminal, but I need my script to know its PID and writing `ps aux | grep screen` in the script doesn't help much... Also, there will always be at least two results out of that command in my case.

Comment: Okay lets take a step back, if it is running in screen - you should be able to see it with screen -ls. Are you running the screen -ls command as the same user as the user who owns the screen session?

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea... I know there's only one user on my raspberrypi (user Pi) and that the terminal always has `pi@raspberrypi`. So I'm assuming yes, I am running it as the same user.

Comment: Did you start the screen manually? I would really try to figure that out first, because I cant think of any other reason why you would not be able to see it with screen -ls other then it being run by as another user or not running at all. Check what is inside the /var/run/screen, you should be able to find all screens under each user there.

Comment: No, I didnt start it manually. The command I wrote above starts the screen through my script. Basically opens screen in detached mode and runs there. But i just tested running a `screen -d -m -S Test sleep 999` and the command in my actual script, both manually in the terminal and surprisingly Test shows up but my other command from the script doesnt...

Comment: Using `ps` in scripts in not considered good form when alternatives are available -- it's extremely error-prone; `grep foo` might find someone running `vim foo.conf`. [BashFAQ #33](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/033) discusses alternatives (and, particular, how those processes should be used if the context is any kind of daemon management; [ProcessManagement](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement) is also pertinent).

Comment: @berend I figured out why `screen -ls` wasnt showing up my detached session. I ran screen once at the start of the program and inside that new screen session I started another `screen` session. Since it was a "screen inside another screen" it wouldnt show up one of those screens (the most inner one).